# Javascript cannot read div from html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code which is connected to a htlm called "***old.html***". I do thing in there and then I have another html called "***new.html***" in which I want to add html elements in there.

I have this code in which I try to assign the `div` ***q1*** to the `variable` ***myVar***.

```
    var printWindow = window.open("http://10.180.101.58:5500/new.html", 'Print');
    var myVar = printWindow.document.getElementById('q1');
```

my html looks like this:

```
<body>

  <form>
    <div id="q1"></div>
  </form>

  <script src="DemoCode.js"></script>
</body>
```

These 2 files are in the same directory, but I think the problem is with the `window.open()`

I can't do `document.getElementById()` because I also have the "***old.html***" which let's say is the original html connected to my javascript and whenever I call `document.getElementById()` it gets elements from that one.

Does anyone know any way so that I can get elements from "***new.html***""?

I am using `<script src="DemoCode.js"></script>` in both html's so I can say that both are connected to my javaScript.

Comment: Are the old.html and new.html in **Same-origin**?

Comment: What is the ultimate aim of this? Are you trying to pass data between windows?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius well basically I am creating a website similar to google forms where you can create a survey, and then I have this button generate survey where it generates all the questions created in the editor and shows them in a new window in which it's going to look like the user is seeing it which is different than the one wich the creator of the survey is seeing, so basically yeah I have to pass data

Comment: One easy way to do that perhaps would be to use a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) or [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)?

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers here:

1. If the window where the code doing this is on the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) (`http://10.180.101.58:5500`),
   you have to wait for the DOM to be loaded in the new window (for instance, using the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event) before you can access it.
2. If the window where the code doing this *isn't* on the same origin as the new window you're opening, then you can't access its DOM, since of course that would be a massive security hole.

Here's how you'd do it in case #1:

```
const printWindow = window.open("http://10.180.101.58:5500/new.html", "Print");
printWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const myVar = printWindow.document.getElementById("q1");
    // ...use it here...
});
```

---

> I am using `<script src="DemoCode.js"></script>` in both html's so I can say that both are connected to my javaScript.

That doesn't in any way connect the windows (imagine all the windows that would be connected by jQuery or React loaded from a CDN!). All it does is load the code in that file into both windows.

Comment: Both html's are in the same origin. I used your code and I found another problem. In "old.html" I have a <form> to which I have an eventListener (`questionnaire.onclick = ev => {...`) and because I have only 1 `.js` file it is trying to execute this code and it crashes because the "new.html" doesn't contain the `questionnaire` and it is null and it crashes

Comment: @ChrisCosta - As you say, that's a different problem than the question above. But FWIW, sounds like you shouldn't be using the same code on both pages, or at least update the code to handle the fact something may not exist because it's only on one or the other.

Comment: Is there a way I can do 2 `.js` files which one will be for the one html and the other will be for the other html but both `.js` files can share common global variables?

Comment: @ChrisCosta - They don't share the same common global variables even if they **are** the same file. Each page has its own environment, and the globals declared by scripts included in the page are created in that environment. They aren't shared. If you want to share information between two pages from the same origin, you can use [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).